# Inifinite Scroll distance property ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, distance

Is there a way to handle the distance tag adding `distance="1%"` like Ionic 1, but I want it in Ionic 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have look at the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/infinite-scroll/InfiniteScroll/) you will see that there is a `threshold` property listed under Input properties. Right next to it there is an explanation which says the *distance* can be specified either in `%` or in `px`:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll threshold="30%" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```